# How to provide the CSRF Token in single page application (spring security)?

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf, single-page-application

When I try to load part of a page using ajax I got 403 error

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Spring Security FAQ tells us

> If an HTTP 403 Forbidden is returned for HTTP POST, but works for HTTP
>   GET then the issue is most likely related to CSRF. Either provide the
>   CSRF Token or disable CSRF protection (not recommended).

So, how can a do this?

```
function getPage(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {_csrf: "??"},
        success: function (data) {
            loadPage(url, data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the token from the cookie which is stored at your client. For that you have to use something like this cookie-service:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie

write a function like this to get the token:

```
getCookie(){
    return this._cookieService.get("token-name");
}
```

Finaly add the token to the request header:

```
doSomething(token){
    var json = JSON.stringify({});
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
     headers.append('token-name', token);
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/doSomething', json, {
        headers: headers
    }).map(res => res.text()
    );
}
```

This solved the problem for me

Answer (score -2):

Found an answer to my own question here:
http://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/

this - to html

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

this - to js

```
$(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a scenario where I don't serve the single page app via Spring. It's served from another web server and it needs to perform requests to my API.